# Show that two definitions of the controllability Gramians are equivalent

Tags: reference-request, definition, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

Given a dynamical system $\dot x = Ax + Bu$, I've noticed that several authors define the controllability Gramian as:

$$W = \int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)} BB^T e^{A^T(t-\tau)}d\tau$$

while others define it as,
$$W = \int_0^te^{A\tau} BB^T e^{A^T\tau}d\tau$$

More strangely, I see other places define them simultaneously as follows:
$$W = \int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)} BB^T e^{A^T(t-\tau)}d\tau = \int_0^te^{A\tau} BB^T e^{A^T\tau}d\tau$$

For instance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controllability_Gramian

What gives? I know that this integral is not easy to evaluate. So how do I show that they are actually equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One integral is obtained from another using a change of variables:
$$
\int_0^te^{A(t-\tau)} BB^T e^{A^T(t-\tau)}d\tau=\left| s=t-\tau\atop ds=-d\tau
\right|=
-\int_{t-0}^{t-t}e^{As} BB^T e^{A^Ts}ds
$$
$$
=-\int_{t}^{0}e^{As} BB^T e^{A^Ts}ds=\int^{t}_{0}e^{As} BB^T e^{A^Ts}ds.
$$